# How to get a list of all months from current month to a month in the past using moment.js

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, momentjs

I'm trying to generate a list of months starting from April 2020 to a month in the past ( October 2019 ) using [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/).

```js
const start = moment().startOf('month')
const startMonth = moment('10-01-2019', 'MM-DD-YYYY').format('MMMM YYYY')
const month = moment().startOf('month').format('MM')
for (let i = 0; i < month; i++) {
  const m = start.subtract(1, 'month').format('MMMM YYYY')
  if (m === startMonth) {
    break;
  }
  console.log(m)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.26.0/moment.min.js" integrity="sha256-5oApc/wMda1ntIEK4qoWJ4YItnV4fBHMwywunj8gPqc=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

I get only 5 months as a result. Could anyone please help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using [`isSameOrBefore()`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-same-or-before/)

```js
const start = moment().startOf('month')
const end = moment('11-11-2019', 'MM-DD-YYYY')

while (end.isSameOrBefore(start, 'month')) {
  console.log(start.format('MMMM YYYY'))
  start.subtract(1, 'month')
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.26.0/moment.min.js" integrity="sha256-5oApc/wMda1ntIEK4qoWJ4YItnV4fBHMwywunj8gPqc=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Exclude current month

```js
const start = moment().startOf('month')
const end = moment('11-11-2019', 'MM-DD-YYYY')

while (end.isBefore(start, 'month')) {
  start.subtract(1, 'month')
  console.log(start.format('MMMM YYYY'))
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.26.0/moment.min.js" integrity="sha256-5oApc/wMda1ntIEK4qoWJ4YItnV4fBHMwywunj8gPqc=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Wow! That was very neat. How could I exclude the current month?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```js
const start = moment().startOf('month')
const end = moment('10-01-2018', 'MM-DD-YYYY')

let results = []
let current = start
while (current.format('MMMM YYYY') !== end.format('MMMM YYYY')) {
  results.push(current.format('MMMM YYYY'))
  current = current.subtract(1, 'month')
}
// need to add current one last time because the loop will have ended when it is equal to the end date, and will not have added it
results.push(current.format('MMMM YYYY'))

console.log(results)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.26.0/moment.min.js" integrity="sha256-5oApc/wMda1ntIEK4qoWJ4YItnV4fBHMwywunj8gPqc=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Wow! How could I exclude current month in this case?

Comment: Just start one month earlier : `const start = moment().subtract(1, 'month').startOf('month')`

Comment: Fantastic! That was it.